# Merging adjacent polygons using Geopandas by avoiding filling gaps

Tags: geopandas, dissolve

I have raster dataset that I would like to convert into vector polygons. Raster to polygon conversion works pretty good. But, having problem when I  try to merge adjacent polygons using Dissolve function in Geopandas. Gaps inside polygons are automatically filled which I don't want as I want to use those gaps in further analysis. Is there a way to avoid automatically filling gaps?
Here is a simple code:

```
shp = gpd.read_file("file.shp")
shp_dissolved = shp.dissolve(by="VALUE")
shp_dissolved.to_file("dissolved_file.shp")
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]